# Bluetooth Android Audio skips when transferring data over RFCOMM

Tags: android, bluetooth

Hey Guys I'm dealing with an annoying thing.

While I'm sending larger amounts of data over the RFCOMM channel and connected A2DP, the audio will skip while. I've tried a lot of different things the only sure fire way is to space out the data being sent with delays. I'm pretty sure this is a low level Android issue as it mostly happens on 2.3.X but still happens on 4.0

Has anyone seen a similar issue?

Comment: We are fighting the discconnect problem of A2DP when we open an SSP stream for reading from our application. Did you do anything special to make sure the A2DP connection stays opened when SPP is open on Android side? Whic BT device did you use on the remote end?

Comment: The best advice I can give is make sure you pipe the data out as fast as you can and process it on a different thread. It seems the more we kept those channels clear the better the issue got. Make sure to do this on both ends. But still there was no sliver bullet to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

An A2DP connection can consume the majority of available bluetooth bandwidth.  Once you start adding other RFCOMM packets, you are taking up space that could otherwise be used for A2DP retransmissions, so your ability to hide lost packets is decreased.  Other portions of bandwidth can be lost if your device is doing periodic page or inquiry scans, so you might want to ensure that is not happening.  Basically, I wouldn't have too much expectation of running A2DP and RFCOMM at the same time unless your RFCOMM traffic is extremely low.

Comment: Yea this is exactly what I was worried about. I haven't looked at the Bluez stack directly, but I'm guessing it doesn't have any packet priority set up, which is disappointing.